Share groups with Podman containers
I'm having problems granting access of some directories to a specific container that are accessible by some groups that externally managed (LDAP).
When using podman run, I'm able to use the --groups-add keep-groups option. Another option, as explained here, is to use --annotation run.oci.keep_original_groups=1

Thing is, I want to use podman compose up instead due to convenience.
Since some groups are external, i can't mount the /etc/group.
Tried different variations modifying the docker-compose.yml with group_adds (which allows me to add certain groups to the user but they aren't recognized from the host and if I create that group in the Dockerfile with the same group host GID it behaves as a new group still), as well as using podman compose --pod-args="..." which returns either unknown flag --group-add or --annotation.

To fix I've changed in /etc/containers/conf to include
[containers]
userns = "keep-id"
annotations=["run.oci.keep_original_groups=1"]

as suggested here. This makes all of the containers share the users groups.
